# Django Polling of Import script - need user status update. Use model? Sessions?

Tags: ajax, django, session

I have an application where a user uploads a file, then there is some processing of those files that I take care of. The process can take minutes, so I want to send regular updates to the user about what is going on.

Right now I'm thinking of implementing Ajax polling to a view which renders json. The problem is that I don't currently have a mechanism for that view to grab the status data.  For something like a status update, it seems weird to put that into a model for the view to access, but is that the best route? Am I better off going a different route like storing the status data in user sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an issue with a `Job` model that your background processing updates and then a view that your JavaScript polls. It may be useful in the future for analytics, too -- you could track how long processing takes on average for files of a specific size, for example.

Roughly, something like this:

```
class Job(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='jobs')
     status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Then, on file upload, create a new `Job`, and pass it to your front-end so that it can poll the job status view you create.

Comment: Thanks for this. I figured as much but it's always helpful to validate that there's not a better way.